# Filtering in JavaScript with radio button using D3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radio-button, scatter-plot, input-filtering

I am trying to use a set of radio buttons to filter between data on a D3 scatter plot diagram. My scatter plot diagram is based on  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663. I have only modified the code to fit my data needs. The code in the link is very close to what I have.

The code in my CSV file is arranged in the following way.

```
DataType1,DataType2,DataType3,DataType4,
  1,2,3,4
  1,2,3,4
  1,2,3,4
  1,2,3,4
  1,2,3,4
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: Sorry. My question is how would I control the filtering of the data by using radio buttons?

Comment: You would attach a handler function to the radio buttons which changes the data set accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, here is my code:

```
Open<input type="radio" name="Status" id="radio-open" value="Open" onClick="window.location.reload()" />
    Closed<input type="radio" name="Status" id="radio-closed" value="Closed" onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
    Clear<input type="radio" name="Status" id="radio-clear" value="Clear" onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
```

And:

```
  if (!document.getElementById('radio-clear').checked) {
    if (document.getElementById('radio-open').checked) {
      data = data.filter(function(d) { return d["Status"] == "Open"; })
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('radio-closed').checked) {
      data = data.filter(function(d) { return d["Status"] == "Closed"; })
    }
```

}